# How do I access a docker insecure registry from a Windows docker on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have 2 machines running dockerd. One an Ubunto.18.04 box with docker version 18.06.1-ce installed, which I want to use as an insecure test registry/repository server where the only way I'll use it is to use a SSH tunnel in to port 5000.

The other is a development workstation, a Windows 10 'pro' box which also has a local instance of docker (docker for Windows version 18.06.1-ce) running as a service on it which I am using to build test images.

So far I can't get the Windows box to push to or pull from the Ubuntu box through the tunnel.

Both dockerds are running. I added the insecure registries setting on the workstation ( via the docker GUI, I could not find the `daemon.json` file so assume it is in the Windows registry or a hidden location?)

I added localhost:5000 to test for using the SSHE tunnel and `Dev2:5000` (temporary for this test opened port 5000 on the internal subnet) to test a direct connection without the tunnel, and restarted docker.

On the registry box I followed the sample of how to use a private registry and did the below to test it. I was logged to "Dev2" as a user I added to the "docker" group that also has `sudo` privileges. I also tried as root.

```
Dev2:> docker pull ubuntu:18.04
# success

Dev2:> docker tag ubuntu:18.04 localhost:5000/testapp:00.01
Dev2:> docker push localhost:5000/testapp/00.01
# success

Dev2:> docker tag ubuntu:18.04 Dev2:5000/testapp:00.02
Dev2:> docker push Dev2:5000/testapp/00.02
# success

Dev2:> docker image rm ubuntu:18.04
# success

Dev2:> docker image ls -a

REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
localhost:5000/testapp   00.01               ea4c82dcd15a        40 hours ago        85.8MB
Dev2:5000/testapp        00.02               ea4c82dcd15a        40 hours ago        85.8MB
registry                 2                   2e2f252f3c88        5 weeks ago         33.3MB


Dev2:> curl http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["testapp"]}

Dev2:>  curl http://localhost:5000/v2/testapp/tags/list
{"name":"testapp","tags":["00.01","00.02"]}

Dev2:> curl http://Dev2:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["testapp"]}

Dev2:> curl http://Dev2:5000/v2/testapp/tags/list
{"name":"testapp","tags":["00.01","00.02"]}
```

At this point all seems to be fine. If I delete the images on the Dev2 docker and pull them they are extracted from the repository and re-added to the docker instance.

Now I try to pull the images into docker on the workstation.

I run a ssh tunnel ssh on the Windows 10 workstation ( Msys GNU version)

```
workstation:> ssh nyc.livingwork.com -L 5000:localhost:5000 &  # this runs and the tunnel workstation
```

I also try using a browser (no curl here) with URLs:

http://Dev2:5000/v2/testapp/tags/list
and
http://localhost:5000/v2/testapp/tags/list

And I get for both:
{"name":"testapp","tags":["00.01","00.02"]}

So the server is accessible both direct and through tunnel.

Now I try:

```
workstation:$ docker pull localhost:5000/testapp:00.01
Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

workstation:> docker pull Dev2:5000/testapp:00.02
Error response from daemon: Get http://Dev2:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The timeout is at least 30 seconds.
Note: if I do the same thing from another Unix box running docker everything works right so this is particular to docker for Windows running on Windows 10. For some reason this fails.

I haven't been able to solve this. There are no HTTP proxies in the chain on either machine. It is on a local subnet. All other services on the server are accessible, etc. The "insecure-registries" in the Windows docker in the UI is set for both hosts and ports.

Is it a bug? In Windows 10 docker? It works fine from another Ubuntu box.

Comment: you are verifying things using curl , and then you are using docker client , curl is not the same as docker client

Comment: @IjazKhan for sure.  But curl verifies the http: access is working just fine for the API calls the client uses.

If I try to connect with HTTPS it fails with a invalid credentials error when trying to connect to port 5000 both though the tunnel, direct, and in the server.  So it likely has something to do with the client.  From the docker docs "With insecure registries enabled, Docker goes through the following steps:

First, try using HTTPS.
If HTTPS is available but the certificate is invalid, ignore the error about the certificate.
If HTTPS is not available, fall back to HTTP.

Comment: Did you add your unsecure registry in the Docker Desktop Settings-->Docker Engine section?

Comment: Side question about this: where does one save the `daemon.json` in Windows? Is it `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon)?

Answer (score 12):

I was experiencing the same problem. I was able to "fix" it by going to `daemon.json`, and disabling the experimental features. Here's my json config:

```json
{
  "insecure-registries": [
    "localhost:5000"
  ],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "registry-mirrors": []
}
```